# How to get the value of variable inside javascript function passing to php variable

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

This is my code inside a form, displaying the period and year to be selected.
As you can see I have a button there at the button (not a submit button) calling a modal. So what i need its to pass the value of period and year inputted in the modal. I have not wrote down the entire code inside the form just the important scripts needed to emphasize my question.

```
<form name="myform" id="myform" action="index.php" method="post">
<input></input> //input of period
<input></input> //input of year
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-large" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"  id="range">Assign Payout Schedule</button>
</form>
```

Here is my Modal. So in here, I have a code that sets the period and year that was passed from the inputted value from the form above, but it doesn't get the value having the post method,I really have a doubt on this because I didn't use submit button and the reason I didn't use the ajax method is because inside the modal I cannot get the value from the database to be displayed in the modal, that was the first problem arise that's why I change my code into this, Now using the function getPeriod i can get the values using document.getElementByid but how can I pass those variables in a php variable so i can set those variable in my setters? I've been stuck on this so it is really a big help if anyone can find a solution on this case. Or if there's another way to do it just tell me.

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

<script type="text/javascript">

//getPeriod();

function getPeriod(){

var period = document.getElementById("quarter").value; 
var year = document.getElementById("year").value; 

 }
```

```
<?php

    $Payroll_Summary = new Payroll_Summary();
    $Payroll_Summary->setPeriodCovered(period]);
    $Payroll_Summary->setYear(year);
    $data = $Payroll_Summary->getStartEndDateRange();
            foreach($data as $dataList){  
            $var1 = $dataList['start_date_range'];
            $var2 = $dataList['end_date_range'];

            $sdr = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($var1));
            $edr = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($var2));} ?>

<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times; </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Payroll Summary</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
<p> Start Date - End Date (Range):<?php echo $sdr.'-'.$edr; ?> </p> 
    Start Date &nbsp;<input class="input-large" type="date" name="start_date" id="start_date" value="<?php echo $_POST['start_date']; ?>"  onchange="checkStartDate('<?php echo $var1;?>','<?php echo $var2;?>');"><br />
    End Date &nbsp;<input class="input-large" type="date" name="end_date" id="end_date" value="<?php echo $_POST['end_date']; ?>"  onchange="ajaxTxnList();"><br />
    FO Remarks&nbsp;<input class="input-large" type="text" name="fo_remarks" id="fo_remarks" value="<?php echo $_POST['fo_remarks'];?>" onchange="ajaxTxnList();" ><br />
</div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
  <?php if($_SESSION[ewSessionUserLevel] == "5" || $_SESSION[ewSessionUserLevel] == "-1"){ ?>   
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="generatePayrollSummary('2','1','1','1')" data-dismiss="modal">Update</button>
   <?php }else{?>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="generatePayrollSummary('2','1','1','2')" data-dismiss="modal">Update</button>
   <?php }?>
   <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button> -->
  </div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function checkStartDate(sdr,edr){

var start_date = document.getElementById("start_date").value; 
var start_date_range = sdr;
var end_date_range = edr;

if(start_date < start_date_range || start_date > end_date_range){
    //document.getElementById('warning1').innerHTML = "Invalid Start Date! Should be between Start-End Date Range.";
    alert("Invalid Start Date! Must be between start-end date range.");
}
}

</script>
```

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking, could you try and rephrase your question?

Comment: Php is interpreted on the server side before javascript(which is on client side), so if you get a value by using javascript code, you either use ajax and send that value to php wher you can also connect to your database for values, or you open a new php send by sending this values as parameters.

Comment: how to do it in ajax?